# Creating a command line graphic setup/install

Tags: linux, unix, graphics, dialog

I have custom scripts that I have added to my raspberry pi using Raspbian. I would like to make a graphic install/config for my software preferences, such as that in the image below. I have found some other posts on Stack Overflow on [dialog(1) utility](http://www.unixcl.com/2009/12/linux-dialog-utility-short-tutorial.html), but It appears old and outdated since the date is 2009. Is there a newer or better program for accomplishing this?

[image]
[image]